# Адаптивное масштабирование и позиционирование css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Хочу сделать круг (для начала квадрат), но не знаю как сделать его полностью адаптивным (корректное отображение на всех разрешениях), чтобы он всегда сохранял форму(пропорцию высота/ширина). А также отображение его по-середине страницы. Желательно на css чистом, приемлимо js

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3k0ej1p7/ https://jsfiddle.net/3k0ej1p7/1/  А вообще почитайте основы как сделать квадрат и круг, в интернете информации тонны.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.circle {
width:  15%;
background: #900C3F;
border-radius:  50%;
text-align: center;
font-size:  18px;
margin: 0 auto;
cursor: pointer;
transition: 1s;
}


window.onload = function() {
   var circle = document.querySelectorAll(".circle");
   var circIn = document.querySelectorAll(".circle__inv");
   for(var i = 0;i<circle.length;i++) {
      circle[i].style.height = circle[i].offsetWidth + "px";
   }
};

<div class="circle">
  <div class="circle__inv">
     <span class="count__hgt">Выберите интересующую тему</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

circle__inv нужен для дальнейшей коррекции текста(padding-top) без костылей, вроде статических значений

Answer (score 1):

как вариант, единицы измерения `vh` дадут адаптивность в зависимости от разрешения

```css
.square {
  background: #000;
  width: 10vh;
  height: 10vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* border-radius: 50%; */
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

для превращения квадрата в круг уберите комментарий `border-radius: 50%;`

Answer (score 0):

```css
.b-square {
  width: 100%;
  background: #f00;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

.b-square:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.b-circle {
  width: 100%;
  background: #00f;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 15px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.b-circle:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-square"></div>
<div class="b-circle"></div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/cppohv8d/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: blue;
}

.square, .circle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 29%;
  background: silver;
  text-align: center;
}

.square:before, .circle:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.contents {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
  <div class=contents>Square</div>
</div>
<div class="circle">
  <div class=contents>Circle</div>
</div>
```