# Как сделать содержимое контейнера адаптивным к его размерам?

Tags: css

Есть контейнер с заданными размерами в котором будет находится какой-то элемент с заранее не известными размерами. То есть ширина может быть больше или наоборот высота, но занимать он должен все пространство родителя не изменяя пропорции. Возможно ли сделать этот элемент адаптивным по размерам подобно способу с `background-image: ...` + `background-size: cover` , без `js`?

Comment: Знаю только для одного из направлений: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/480185/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy, одно направление, это `width: 100%; height: auto;` или наоборот. наверное нельзя так сделать, уже не первый раз ищу подобное и ни разу не находил.

Comment: Вообще-то `width` в процентах сколько угодно и вместо `height` использовать `padding-top`. А вот как высоту взять за основу, пока не придумал.

Comment: Ну и при помощи svg точно можно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например на абсолюте:

```css
.wrap {
  max-width: 400px;
  min-height: 300px;
  height: 100%;  
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.box {  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box">
    Внутренний блок
  </div>
</div>
```

Или вариант с flex:

```css
.wrap {
  max-width: 400px;
  min-height: 300px;
  height: 100%;  
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    justify-content: center;
}

.box {  
  width: 100%;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box">
    Внутренний блок
  </div>
</div>
```

**+** вариант для Вашего комментария):

```css
.wrap {
  max-width: 400px;
  min-height: 300px;
  height: 100%;  
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.box {  
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #eee;
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px){
  .box {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img class="box" src="http://co.forum4.ru/uploads/0003/cd/5c/5095-5-f.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за старания, но к моему сожалению, это не то... Вот как работает ваш пример - https://jsbin.com/ginaliboku/4/edit?html,css,output, а вот как нужно мне - https://jsbin.com/gabociqeke/3/edit?html,css,output  при чем так должно быть с картинками любого масштаба.